# How to get ID of a newly created SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Say, I run the following statement to create a new SQL Server database:

```
CREATE DATABASE [testdb1] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;
```

How do I get it's ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT database_id FROM sys.databases WHERE name = N'testdb1';
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it in any way different from using `DB_ID` function?

Comment: @ahmd0 I generally try to stay away from the metadata functions, since many of them block. If this command gets blocked, I can change the isolation level. I can't do that with the functions. [See this Connect item for more information (and confirmation that it won't be fixed)](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/432497/metadata-functions-should-follow-same-isolation-semantics-as-metadata-queries).

Answer (score 4):

```
select DB_ID (N'testdb1')
```

[Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186274.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, that was easy. Although you should probably correct it to `select DB_ID(N'testdb1');`

Comment: Although this is a correct reply, I can't mark it as answer because the original post contains a syntactic error.

Comment: True, the syntax diagram includes the `[ ]` not as part of the syntax but to show that the name is optional (e.g. `SELECT DB_ID();` will give you the database_id of the current database without having to specify the name).